# Transpose a table using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| A | type | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| first | B | 20 |
| second | B | 30 |
| first | C | 200 |
| second | C | 300 |

I need to get it to look like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| first | 20 | 200 |
| second | 30 | 300 |

How do I do this using Pandas? I tried using transpose, but couldn't get it to this exact table.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.pivot('A','type')
df.columns = [x[1] for x in list(df.columns)]
df.reset_index()
```